# Duplicated font-size property

Tags: css

Could you explain please, what this code mean

```
 h1{
    font-size: 36px !important;
    font-size: 3.6rem!important;
  }
```

Or this

```
body {
  background: $backgroundColor;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
}
```

Why is there duplicated `font-size` properties?

Comment: In older browsers rem values are not supported so px are for backward compatability.

Comment: This is a very standard CSS rule. If you write `font-size: 2rem` and compile it with `autoprefixer` plugin (https://www.npmjs.com/package/autoprefixer), this is what it gets compiled to.

Comment: The duplicated declaration are for fallback. Read more here https://modernweb.com/using-css-fallback-properties-for-better-cross-browser-compatibility/

Comment: I don’t think those duplicate questions ask the same one this does fwiw.

Comment: @D_N No, they don't, they ask how to best deal with fallbacks, which this one asks about, hence I found the questions themselves answering this one, and by that be a reasonable dupe

Comment: @LGSon if I am googling and do not know about fallbacks, this is what my Q is, not how to do it. So I disagree there.

Comment: @D_N The good part now is they are linked, so they back up each other being as related as two can, not being the exact same, which I find useful. And note, there are 2 answers here explaining why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, here’s the full rundown.

`rem` is a unit that does not work or is significantly buggy in older browsers, notably IE. [See the CanIUse entry.](https://caniuse.com/#feat=rem)

CSS allows you to declare a rule multiple times, with the last one winning. This is often used to feed old or noncompliant browsers a fallback value which a newer or compliant browser will *also* read but will *then overwrite* with the last value given.

So:

```css
.example {
  font-size: 12px;
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  background-color: blue;
  background-color: red;
}
```

Any browser will decide the background color is red (not blue), and any up-to-date browser will set the font size at 1.1rem. But a browser that does not understand what “rem” is will discard that rule and keep the prior one (12px).

Answer (score 0):

The duplicated declarations use for fallback in order to support older browsers.

The  !important declarations use to override rules and consider not a good practice.

As for your question regarding font-size units - the rem is not supported with legacy browsers.

MDN have very good explanation about HTML and  CSS fallback behaviour: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Tools_and_testing/Cross_browser_testing/HTML_and_CSS

Hope that helps.